# Autoplay and stop on opening and closing modal

Tags: javascript, video, modal-dialog, autoplay

I'm new to javascript and am facing issues with auto-playing video and stopping video upon opening and closing the modal.

Currently this script allows me to close the modal if I click outside of the video control and has to be fixed as well. It is intended to be able to play/pause the video on click of the video body, and modal to be closed when clicked out of the video.

At the same time, upon opening the modal, the video should be able to play automatically, likewise while closing the modal, video stop.

I am not familiar with the functions and if anyone could possibly suggest any improvement on the current script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <style>
            .trailer{
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index: 1;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .trailer.active{
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .trailer #mainvid{
            position: relative;
            max-width: 1200px;
            outline: none;
        }

        .trailer-close{
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            right: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
            filter: invert(1);
            max-width: 32px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 991px) {
            .trailer #mainvid{
                max-width: 90%;
            }
        }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="banner">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Testing Testing 1 2 3</p>
                <a href="#" onclick="toggle();">
                    <button>Play Video</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="trailer" id="main">
            <video id="mainvid" src="/video/products/container accomodation/main/main video.mp4" controls="true"></video>
        </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(){
            var trailer = document.querySelector(".trailer")
            trailer.classList.toggle("active");
            video.pause();
            video.currentTime = 0;
        }

        window.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
            var traileractive = document.querySelector(".trailer.active")
            traileractive.classList.toggle("active");
        })

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle states of the video player, we can simply use the `play` `pause` functions of `HTMLMediaElement`. Use this code, it handles all the desired functionalities.

```js
var videoElem = document.querySelector(".trailer video");
var trailerElem = document.querySelector(".trailer")

function toggle() {
  trailerElem.classList.add("active");
  videoElem.play();
  videoElem.currentTime = 0;
}

function handleTrailerClick(event) {
  if (event && event.target && event.target.nodeName !== "VIDEO") {
    videoElem.pause();
    trailerElem.classList.remove('active');
  }
}

function handleVideoClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  videoElem.paused ? videoElem.play() : videoElem.pause();
}

document.querySelector("#playButton").addEventListener('click', toggle)
document.querySelector(".trailer").addEventListener('click', handleTrailerClick);
document.querySelector(".trailer video").addEventListener('click', handleVideoClick);
```

```css
.trailer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.trailer.active {
  display: flex;
}

.trailer #mainvid {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  outline: none;
}

.trailer-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: invert(1);
  max-width: 32px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .trailer #mainvid {
    max-width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Testing Testing 1 2 3</p>
    <button id="playButton">Play Video</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="trailer" id="main">
  <video id="mainvid" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4" controls="true"></video>
</div>
```